# Optimizing a slow XQuery query in BaseX

Tags: basex, xml-database

I've got a BaseX XML database with only one small XML file. These file basically consists of two structures. One is `PlatformCategory` with 46 instances, the other one `PlatformGenericType` with 213 instances.

`PlatformGenericType` has references to `PlatformCategory` in the `href` attribute.

```
<PlatformGeneralType id="/plib/platformgeneraltypes/pgt1">
  <name>No statement</name>
  <enum>NO_STATEMENT</enum>
  <isOfPlatformCategory href="/plib/platformcategories/pc1"/>
  <readOnly>true</readOnly>
</PlatformGeneralType>

<PlatformCategory id="/plib/platformcategories/pc1">
  <name>No statement</name>
  <enum>NO_STATEMENT</enum>
  <environment>AIR</environment>
  <readOnly>true</readOnly>
</PlatformCategory>
```

When I perform following query, it takes about six seconds to get the result:

```
//PlatformGeneralType[isOfPlatformCategory/@href=//PlatformCategory[environment="AIR"]/@id]
```

What can I do to optimize this query?

Note that I ran "optimize all".

**Update**: The issue on the previous query seems to be solved. But when I extends the query with following, the query takes 44,28 seconds:

```
/PLib/PlatformSpecificTypes/PlatformSpecificType
[isOfPlatformGeneralType/@href=/PLib/PlatformGeneralTypes/PlatformGeneralType
    [isOfPlatformCategory/@href=/PLib/PlatformCategories/PlatformCategory
        [environment='AIR']/@id]/@id]
```

The there are 8939 instances of `PlatformSpecificType` and its structure:

```
<PlatformSpecificTypes>
    <PlatformSpecificType id="/plib/platformspecifictypes/DataShip.3">
        <name>Meko 360H2</name>
        <lethalityLevel>LOW</lethalityLevel>
        <isOfPlatformGeneralType href="/plib/platformgeneraltypes/pgt62"/>
        <ownedByCountry href="/plib/countries/10"/>
    </PlatformSpecificType>
</PlatformSpecificTypes>
```

Its query info:

Query:
    /PLib/PlatformSpecificTypes/PlatformSpecificType[isOfPlatformGeneralType/@href=/PLib/PlatformGeneralTypes/PlatformGeneralType[isOfPlatformCategory/@href=/PLib/PlatformCategories/PlatformCategory[environment='AIR']/@id]/@id]
    Result:
    - Hit(s): 3642 Items
    - Updated: 0 Items
    - Printed: 2048 KB
    - Read Locking: local [command_plib]
    - Write Locking: none
    Timing:
    - Parsing: 1.25 ms
    - Compiling: 0.71 ms
    - Evaluating: 44248.94 ms
    - Printing: 37.11 ms
    - Total Time: 44288.02 ms
    Query plan:

Database properties:

```
Database Properties
 Name: command_plib
 Size: 20247 KB
 Nodes: 781606
 Documents: 1
 Binaries: 0
 Timestamp: 2015-06-12-10-12-14

Resource Properties
 Input Path: /home/sceran/Documents/PLIB/command_plib.xml
 Input Size: 21354 KB
 Timestamp: 2015-06-11-15-34-07
 Encoding: UTF-8
 CHOP: true

Indexes
 Up-to-date: true
 TEXTINDEX: true
 ATTRINDEX: true
 FTINDEX: false
 LANGUAGE: English
 STEMMING: true
 CASESENS: true
 DIACRITICS: false
 STOPWORDS: 
 UPDINDEX: false
 AUTOOPTIMIZE: false
 MAXCATS: 100
 MAXLEN: 96
```

Query info:

```
Compiling:
- rewriting descendant-or-self step(s)
- rewriting descendant-or-self step(s)
- converting descendant::*:PlatformGeneralType[(*:isOfPlatformCategory/@*:href = root()/descendant::*:PlatformCategory[(*:environment = "AIR")]/@*:id)] to child steps
Query:
//PlatformGeneralType[isOfPlatformCategory/@href=//PlatformCategory[environment="AIR"]/@id]
Optimized Query:
db:open-pre("command_plib",0)/*:PLib/*:PlatformGeneralTypes/*:PlatformGeneralType[(*:isOfPlatformCategory/@*:href = root()/descendant::*:PlatformCategory[(*:environment = "AIR")]/@*:id)]
Result:
- Hit(s): 55 Items
- Updated: 0 Items
- Printed: 12776 Bytes
- Read Locking: local [command_plib]
- Write Locking: none
Timing:
- Parsing: 0.55 ms
- Compiling: 0.3 ms
- Evaluating: 5786.29 ms
- Printing: 1.0 ms
- Total Time: 5788.15 ms
Query plan:
<QueryPlan compiled="true">
  <IterPath>
    <DBNode name="command_plib" pre="0"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PLib"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlatformGeneralTypes"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlatformGeneralType">
      <CmpG op="=">
        <CachedPath>
          <IterStep axis="child" test="*:isOfPlatformCategory"/>
          <IterStep axis="attribute" test="*:href"/>
        </CachedPath>
        <IterPath>
          <Root/>
          <IterStep axis="descendant" test="*:PlatformCategory">
            <CmpG op="=">
              <CachedPath>
                <IterStep axis="child" test="*:environment"/>
              </CachedPath>
              <Str value="AIR" type="xs:string"/>
            </CmpG>
          </IterStep>
          <IterStep axis="attribute" test="*:id"/>
        </IterPath>
      </CmpG>
    </IterStep>
  </IterPath>
</QueryPlan>
```

**Update two:**
I suspect the structure of PlatformSpecificTypes prevents indexing. I am wondering if I change it as below, will it improves the query performance?

```
<PlatformSpecificTypes>
    <PlatformSpecificType id="/plib/platformspecifictypes/DataShip.3">
        <name>Meko 360H2</name>
        <lethalityLevel>LOW</lethalityLevel>
        **<isOfPlatformGeneralType>/plib/platformgeneraltypes/pgt62 </isOfPlatformGeneralType>**
        <ownedByCountry href="/plib/countries/10"/>
    </PlatformSpecificType>
</PlatformSpecificTypes>
```

**Update three:**
I have uploaded the [XML file in a gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/821b74d26e631a07f212), so that you can inspect it.

Now, when I execute following query, I takes about 28 seconds to get the result.

```
/root/PlSpTys/PlSpTy[isOfPlGeTy/@href=/root/PlGeTys/PlGeTy[isOfPlCt/@href=/root/PlCts/PlCt[environment='AIR']/@id]/@id]
```

Here is the query info:

```
 Query:
/root/PlSpTys/PlSpTy[isOfPlGeTy/@href=/root/PlGeTys/PlGeTy[isOfPlCt/@href=/root/PlCts/PlCt[environment='AIR']/@id]/@id]
Result:
- Hit(s): 3642 Items
- Updated: 0 Items
- Printed: 257 KB
- Read Locking: local [Output6]
- Write Locking: none
Timing:
- Parsing: 0.66 ms
- Compiling: 0.34 ms
- Evaluating: 28398.32 ms
- Printing: 4.63 ms
- Total Time: 28403.97 ms
Query plan:
<QueryPlan compiled="true">
  <IterPath>
    <DBNode name="Output6" pre="0"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="*:root"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlSpTys"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlSpTy">
      <CmpG op="=">
        <CachedPath>
          <IterStep axis="child" test="*:isOfPlGeTy"/>
          <IterStep axis="attribute" test="*:href"/>
        </CachedPath>
        <IterPath>
          <Root/>
          <IterStep axis="child" test="*:root"/>
          <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlGeTys"/>
          <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlGeTy">
            <CmpG op="=">
              <CachedPath>
                <IterStep axis="child" test="*:isOfPlCt"/>
                <IterStep axis="attribute" test="*:href"/>
              </CachedPath>
              <IterPath>
                <Root/>
                <IterStep axis="child" test="*:root"/>
                <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlCts"/>
                <IterStep axis="child" test="*:PlCt">
                  <CmpG op="=">
                    <CachedPath>
                      <IterStep axis="child" test="*:environment"/>
                    </CachedPath>
                    <Str value="AIR" type="xs:string"/>
                  </CmpG>
                </IterStep>
                <IterStep axis="attribute" test="*:id"/>
              </IterPath>
            </CmpG>
          </IterStep>
          <IterStep axis="attribute" test="*:id"/>
        </IterPath>
      </CmpG>
    </IterStep>
  </IterPath>
</QueryPlan>
```

Could you help me on optimizing the query duration?

Comment: This seems like a rather small dataset. Can you provide a full example, for example in a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) (maybe by anonymizing critical information, if there are any)?

Comment: Actually, in the XML file, there are other structures but not related to the structures I mentioned above (PlatformGenericType, PlatformCategory). In order to provide the example you want, I have removed the other structures from XML file. But when I execute the query, I took only 50.5 msec. Now, I am wondering why those unrelated structures slows down the query?

Comment: So there's more data inside that XML file? How many results are there for `//PlatformCategory[environment="AIR"]/@id`? How long does this part of the query evaluate? Try replacing the `//` with an absolute path; it seems BaseX cannot optimize to child steps here for some reason.

Comment: Are you sure this is doing what you expected? I have the feeling a `/` is missing after the `=` in front of the `PLib` (or is it just missing here?).

Comment: I takes 25.61 ms to get result.  I am very new in BaseX. Could you explain how to get the absolute path?

Comment: when I try following, Unfortunatelly, it still takes 5.6 seconds. //PlatformGeneralType[isOfPlatformCategory/@href=/PLib//PlatformCategory[environment='AIR']/@id]

Comment: An absolute path starts at the root node `/`, and only uses child steps (no descended-or-self steps `//`). `/PLib/PlatformGeneralTypes/PlatformGeneralType` would be an absolute path for the first part of the query (instead of `//PlatformGeneralType). `//` is pretty much always more expensive to evaluate, especially for large subtrees.

Comment: After applying your solution, it takes 13.41 ms now. But when I extend the query as I mention above, it now takes 44.28 seconds. Do you think it is normal with this data structure?

Comment: I don't see how I could give further analysis without any data, the information given is much to incomplete.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the XML here due to license restrictions.

Comment: But the general structure is;  PlatformSpecificType(8939) uses PlatformGeneralType(213) uses PlatformCategory(46). When we start query with environment "AIR", 9 items PlatformCategory in 8 ms,  55 items PlatformGeneralType in 20 ms and 3642 items PlatformSpecificType in 44 seconds return.

Comment: Nobody else to solve this issue?

Comment: Don't expect anybody to give further guesswork to a very vague question. Maybe you can "anonymize" the data.

Comment: @JensErat, I have put the test data. You may want to see Update 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BaseX does not seem to realize it should preprocess the "inner" part with a static result, thus the evaluation costs are somewhere around `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`.

Reformatting your query (which takes around 30 seconds on my machine) to get a better understanding of it shows up the whole right-hand-side of the comparison inside the first predicate being static, not depending on the `PlSpTy` element currently analyzed:

```
/root/PlSpTys/PlSpTy[
  isOfPlGeTy/@href=/root/PlGeTys/PlGeTy[
    isOfPlCt/@href=/root/PlCts/PlCt[
      environment='AIR'
    ]/@id
  ]/@id
]
```

Evaluation of this takes around 9ms on my machine, which is not a lot, but might get expensive if ran repeatedly. Counting the number of `PlSpTy` elements (`count(/root/PlSpTys/PlSpTy)`) reveals close to 8939 such elements, thus the evaluation of the inner part costs around `8939*9ms ~= 80s` -- *something* must have been optimized away, but not everything.

What happens if we simply pull out this part of the query and precompute it?

```
let $compare :=
  /root/PlGeTys/PlGeTy[
    isOfPlCt/@href=/root/PlCts/PlCt[
      environment='AIR'
    ]/@id
  ]/@id

return
  /root/PlSpTys/PlSpTy[
    isOfPlGeTy/@href=$compare
  ]
```

Calculation time drops to 16ms, of which a fourth was used to actually print the results. I opened a [bug report requesting better optimization](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1160). (Update: [some optimizations have been applied](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1160#issuecomment-113525690)).

Comment: I have also tested your solution with the real data. It seems you solved the problem. Thank you for all your help;)

Comment: could you please help me on this issue (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865291/basex-query-optimization-on-join)?

Comment: Some optimizations for this issue [have been included in BaseX, and should be included in the next snapshot soon](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/issues/1160#issuecomment-113525690).

Answer (score 1):

The latest [snapshot of BaseX](http://files.basex.org/releases/latest/) provides an optimization for your query: Results of a path expressions will now be cached if they are requested more than once. The optimization will be officially available with version 8.2.2.